# Does Pandas to_csv in append mode first read the target file into memory?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm hitting out-of-memory errors when working on a big data set in chunks.  The pattern in the memory chart makes me think that appending data to a file using to_csv is actually reading the existing file into memory, appending in-memory, and then dumping it all out to disk.  Is that the way Pandas handles appends to CSVs?

[image: memory]

There are 11 peaks and dips, and this process happens to crash on the 11th iteration.

```
    dfd,dump=tempfile.mkstemp(".csv")
    n_chunks=getNumChunks()
    print(f"Working in {n_chunks} iteration(s).")
    for current_chunk in range(1,n_chunks+1):
        print(f"Iteration {current_chunk} of {n_chunks} ({current_chunk/n_chunks*100:.2f}%)")
        full=mydb.query(f"""
              select colA,colB
              from mytable
              where chunk={current_chunk}
        """)
                
        if full.empty:
            continue
        
        #Get a dataset with the required input cols.
        score_me = full[input_cols].copy()
        print(f"Scoring {len(full)} records.")
        full['value']=clf.predict(score_me)
        
        new=full[['colA','colB','other','cols','tokeep']]
        total_scored+=new.shape[0]
        
        #This is where I append:
        new.to_csv(dump,mode="a+",header=False,index=False)
        new=full=score_me=None
    #End of chunks loop
    print(f"Finished scoring {total_scored:,.0f} records.")
    os.close(dfd)
    os.remove(dump)
```

Comment: I don't think so. The `mode` argument simply gets passed down through lots of calls until it's used in the `open()` function to open the output file.

Comment: [`handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/28f274cb107ef0a252eb4cb954c1cfbe43968395/pandas/io/common.py#L885C13-L885C47)

Comment: I've accepted Nick ODell's answer because it was correct.  However!  I think I've solved the problem, but I don't understand how.  In the first line where I create the temp file I get a file descriptor number (just an int; not a handle or anything).  I don't close that handle until after the loop has finished.  As a wag, I changed the code to create the file with mkstemp and then immediately os.close(dfd).  THEN I do the loop.  THEN I delete the completed file at the very end.  And _this_ fixes my leak.  But I don't understand why leaving the handle open during the loop causes this situation.

Comment: So this has something to do with how tempfile works, not pandas. I can't think of why keeping the FD open would cause a memory leak, either. But why use `tempfile.mkstemp` instead of the higher-level functions like `tempfile.TemporaryFile`?

Comment: And why use a temp file for this in the first place? You're creating the CSV and then immediately deleting it.

Comment: I'm reading chunks of data out of a database, doing some stuff to it, and then storing the results locally.  Once everything has been completed, I push the one big file into the db using a bulk-loading utility.  I'm using mkstemp only to guarantee that there are no conflicts with my filename; I don't want/need the file-like object provide by TemporaryFile.  I guess I _could_ get one and give it to to_csv (which does accept a buffer)...

Comment: The whole point of `tempfile.mkstemp()` returning an FD is so you can use this atomically instead of reopening the filename. You can use `os.fdopen()` to create a python file object connected to the FD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and here's proof.

In order to check whether Pandas is doing this, I wrote a simple test program, and traced it using syscall tracing. In order to read from a file, Pandas would have to use the `read()` syscall, or something similar. It does not.

Here is the test program.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": range(1, 1000000),
    "b": range(2, 1000001),
})
print(df)
# This causes the pandas CSV library to be loaded
df.to_csv("irrelevant.csv")

dump = "test.csv"
print("appending")
df.to_csv(dump, mode="a+")
```

I traced it like this:

```
strace -o trace.log python3 test.py
```

Then, search the trace log for the string "appending." That's when it started writing the dataframe.

Here is every syscall it does between `print("appending")` and when it starts writing the file:

```
write(1, "appending\n", 10)             = 10
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, ".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "test.csv", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=89555580, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 89555580
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffde621b870)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 89555580
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 89555580
mmap(NULL, 1048576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbeece01000
write(3, ",a,b\n0,1,2\n1,2,3\n2,3,4\n3,4,5\n4,5"..., 8189) = 8189
```

To summarize what this is doing:

1. Open the file "test.csv" inside that directory.
2. Get the size of the file.
3. Seek to the end of that file.
4. Check if the file is a terminal.
5. Seek to the end of the file twice more. (Not sure why it does this.)
6. Allocate some memory. (`mmap()` can be used to read files, but it's not being used for that here, because the flags are set to `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.)
7. Start writing.

Since none of those syscalls read files, it is not reading the file before writing.

This test was done using Python 3.10.12 and Pandas 1.5.2.

Comment: I like the use of strace (which I wasn't familiar with before today).  When I was trying to investigate myself I went about a million frames deep in pdb before losing my place.